# AWS Ruby SDK V2: Aws error command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-sdk

I am using cloud9 with ruby on rails, I have just installed the AWS-SDK and was following the amazon documents to set it up (Listed below).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/latest/DeveloperGuide/aws-ruby-sdk-getting-started.html#aws-ruby-sdk-credentials-client

But on the second step which is just to run Aws.config I am getting a Aws command not found error.

I tried with capital letter ect but it is not recognizing AWS.

I was thinking it may possibly be the directory I am in but there is nothing saying I should be in anything but the root directory for my applications. None of he other gems have this problem byt since I am using cloud9 I thought I would check. I have included the director for the gem  below if you think this may be the issue:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-2.3.1
```

This is the output from my console with the top line showing aws-sdk-core 2.3.1 is installed and the errors at the bottom when I try to enter aws into the console.

```
Using aws-sdk-core 2.3.1
    Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
    Using globalid 0.3.6
    Using activemodel 4.2.5
    Using jbuilder 2.4.1
    Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
    Using aws-sdk-resources 2.3.1
    Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
    Using activejob 4.2.5
    Using activerecord 4.2.5
    Using aws-sdk 2.3.1
    Using actionview 4.2.5
    Using actionpack 4.2.5
    Using actionmailer 4.2.5
    Using railties 4.2.5
    Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
    Installing aws-sdk-rails 1.0.1
    Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
    Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
    Using rails 4.2.5
    Using sass-rails 5.0.4
    Using web-console 2.3.0
    Using turbolinks 2.5.3
    Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 65 gems now installed.
    Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
    discoveredfm:~/workspace $ aws
    bash: aws: command not found
    discoveredfm:~/workspace $ Aws
    bash: Aws: command not found
    discoveredfm:~/workspace $ AWS
    bash: AWS: command not found
    discoveredfm:~/workspace $ bundle show aws-sdk
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-2.3.1
    discoveredfm:~/workspace $
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aws-sdk gem (that allows you to access aws services from inside your ruby programs) and the [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (which provides command line access to aws) are two completely separate pieces of software. Installing the gem doesn't install the cli for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `irb` it's pretty cool for check fast things with ruby.

```
% irb
>> require 'aws-sdk'
=> true
>> aws = Aws.new()
```

Just play with aws-sdk , you will need to create credentials and more for the aws resources.

Comment: Thanks @Sergi Case, that is a big help actually.